# How to compile linux-kernel-module using clang

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, clang, kernel-module

I want to build my Linux kernel module (character driver) using clang with the following Makefile

My-Makefile:
[image: My-Makefile]

**System**

Ubuntu: 22.04 LTS
kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic
clang version: 14

I tried using the command:
`make CC=clang-14 HOSTCC=clang-14`

**Error:**

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-fconserve-stack'
> clang: error: unsupported option '-mrecord-mcount' for target 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

Comment: You should use a compiler as close as possible to the one that the kernel was compiled with.

Comment: Required versions are specified in the kernel documentation here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.7/source/Documentation/process/changes.rst  Note clang is allowed.

Comment: A couple of compiler-related configuration options are set at kernel configuration time: `CONFIG_CC_IS_GCC=y` or `CONFIG_CC_IS_CLANG=y`. I think that will have an effect on the compiler flags when building modules. It does on my Debian system with a 5.18 kernel.